# TotallyLazy functional code in Java

Tags: java, android, functional-programming, totallylazy

I am attempting to use the functional library TotallyLazy, in Java. I am programming in AIDE on Android. I have this code which doesn't work:

```
package net.intrepidis;
import java.util.Comparator;
import static com.googlecode.totallylazy.Sequences.sequence;
import static com.googlecode.totallylazy.comparators.Comparators.ascending;

public class FunctionalTest
{
    public static void Go()
    {
        sequence(34, 25, 62)
            .sort(ascending());
    }
}
```

If I use this line instead then it works:

```
            .sort((Comparator<Comparable>)ascending());
```

However, that looks wrong to me, and goes against the grain of the framework. What am I doing wrong? Is it just because the Java version used by AIDE doesn't allow for the abbreviated code?

Comment: `ascending()` is a static method that returns a `Comparator`. I'm confused as to what you're confused about?

Comment: Why do I have to add the casting, and is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the [source for that class](https://code.google.com/p/totallylazy/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/totallylazy/comparators/Comparators.java?spec=svn2237fcb6c4d9259cf52073557573e20415f1b699&r=2237fcb6c4d9259cf52073557573e20415f1b699) it appears you should be calling the version of `ascending()` that accepts a `Class` which will return the appropriate `Comparator`

Comment: I've scoured the 'net for TotallyLazy guides but have found none! Would you know of any? Thanks.

Comment: After spending some time teaching myself how to use TotallyLazy I have created this guide: http://intrepidis.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-totallylazy-functional-library.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do

```
sequence(34, 25, 62)
.sort(Comparators.<Integer>ascending());
```

This is useful if the sequence is a generic type

Answer (score 2):

After following Brian Roach's suggestion I have found that the following works and is much more appropriate:

```
sequence(34, 25, 62)
    .sort(ascending(Integer.class));
```